# Scroll down/up with buttons + Scroll Snap

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently developing a WordPress website with Elementor Pro. My client is asking for up and down buttons to navigate the homepage.

I placed this javascript code to a HTML widget:

```
<script>
    const changeView = (index) => {
  window.scrollTo({ top: window.scrollY + window.innerHeight * index, behavior: 'smooth' });
}
</script>
```

```
<button id="button-up" onclick="changeView(-1)">UP</button>
<button id="button-down" onclick="changeView(1)">DOWN</button>
```

I couldn't make it work with Scroll Snap function in Elementor. If Scroll Snap is enabled, the buttons don't work. Can you help me to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: see the demos in the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)